# [macOS]: Interleave Folder-Structures / Show files from Samba share inside local file system

Tags: mac, samba, file-management

I have a Samba share that has the same folder structure as my home directory on my Mac. I would like to mount the share in such a way that the files in the share appear inside my home directory as if I had merged the two. But the files on the share should stay on the share.

I'd also be ok with using third party software.
I'm using macOS 10.14.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Open your Terminal and type:

```
diff -rq folder1 folder2
```

If you'd prefer a GUI-based tool, FileMerge comes with XCode. Third party options include [BeyondCompare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/) and [Kaleidoscope](https://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/), among others.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I think my original question was poorly phrased. I've rewritten the part that matters. I know about beyond compare, rsync, diff and such. But thanks for trying.

Comment: So you want to have a single point of entry into the file hierarchy where you see both files from your home directory and the Samba share appear in the same folder? If that's indeed what you want, I'm not sure how to accomplish that.